# Responsive HTML Scrolling Box

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently using this HTML scrolling box:

```
<div style="height:107px;width:445px;border:1px 
solid #ccc;font:18px Arial; overflow:auto;"> 
This is an HTML Scrolling Box. </div>
```

All of the text and images on my site are responsive, in the fact that they scale down to the size of mobile phones and tablets. Is there any possible way to add some type of rule or something simple, to this code above that will make it also responsive like the rest of my site?

I have already tried using this bit of code (without luck):

```
style='max-width:100%;' style='max-height:100%' border="0"
```

Thank you!

Comment: 'Responsive'?  You mean that it will change size based on the size of the window?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want it to become larger than its given dimensions. When viewed on larger screens. Only make it smaller, when viewed on devices such as phones and tablets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/ZXVA5/

you want to give the `height` and `width` some percentage.

here is with some content and `overflow:auto`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXVA5/1/

Comment: YES! Although, I had to do a little adjusting. Could you let me know what I can add in there to adjust the font size? It became huge whenever I added that chunk of code you created.

Comment: Actually, I just wrapped it with <fontsize="8"> </font> and it worked

Comment: @Anonymous yes you can set the font size in css as well. dont wrap anything. it will make it ugly. simply put `font-size` in css

Comment: but if you want to adjust the text size accordingly the page size then try the thing in the link

Comment: I have one additional question; don't you know how there's that one line around the text box you just helped me with? How can I add one more line that fits right around that one that's another color? (I want the box to be more stylish, matching my logo).

Comment: The box itself, the square (not the text)...the main box colored red with another box along the outside of that one that is blue

Comment: @btevfik , maybe you can help with that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249696/footer-hides-the-scrollbar-if-the-user-resizes-it-upwards